# Undefined relationship method on query builder - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables `users`, `teams`, `athletes`.

A user can be a team or an athlete.

I put `user_id` in `teams` & `athletes` table.

I put below code in `User.php` model.

```php
public function team()
{
    return $this->hasOne (Team::class);
}


public function athlete()
{
    return $this->hasOne (Athlete::class);
}
```

I put below code in `Team.php` model

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I put below code in `Athlete.php`

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I am using below code in controller.

```
$staff_picks = User::notAdmin()->active()->orderBy('id','desc')->take(10)->team()->athlete()->get();
```

I am getting below error

> laravel.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::team()`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Post your controller's code, where you're performing the query is where the error is at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so the error says

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::team()

That means that the method `team()` is not defined in the class `Builder`

Now the class Builder is in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php` under the namespace `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent`

It logically follows that it's impossible for a function named `team()` to be there right?

---

#### What is team()? then and how can I call it?

`team()` is a function inside your model `app/User.php` and it returns a `hasOne` function

#### Okay so where's `hasOne()`?

`hasOne` is in the trait `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php` under the namespace `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns`

[See here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1bbe5528568555d597582fdbec73e31f8a818dbc/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L55)

```php
namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns;
// Imports ommitted for brevity

trait HasRelationships
{
// Other methods ommitted for brevity

/**
 * Define a one-to-one relationship.
 *
 * @param  string  $related
 * @param  string  $foreignKey
 * @param  string  $localKey
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function hasOne($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
{
    $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);
    $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();
    $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();
    return $this->newHasOne($instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable() . '.' . $foreignKey, $localKey);
}
// Other methods are omitted for brevity
```

#### But how is it called? Am not using HasRelationships trait

That's true, the class `app/User.php` is not using the `HasRelationships` trait but it's extending a class that does*

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
```

*not directly though

> Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

[See Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1bbe5528568555d597582fdbec73e31f8a818dbc/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php#L14)

```php
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

// Other Imports ommitted for brevity
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, MustVerifyEmail;
}
```

And

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model uses the Concerns\HasRelationships trait

[See Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1bbe5528568555d597582fdbec73e31f8a818dbc/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L20)

```php
namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

// Imports ommitted for brevity

abstract class Model implements Arrayable, ArrayAccess, Jsonable, JsonSerializable, QueueableEntity, UrlRoutable
{
    use Concerns\HasAttributes,
        Concerns\HasEvents,
        Concerns\HasGlobalScopes,
        Concerns\HasRelationships, // <-- THERE IT IS HERE!!!!
        Concerns\HasTimestamps,
        Concerns\HidesAttributes,
        Concerns\GuardsAttributes,
        ForwardsCalls;
// Rest of class ommitted for brevity
```

#### Wait! how does this class know where the trait `Concerns\HasRelationships` is coming from without an import?

Because Concerns is a namespace appended (or nested in) to the same namespace this class is defined at

This class in at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` and `HasRelationships` is at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns` so a simple call to `Concerns\HasRelationships` is enough

Now the `HasRelationships` trait has the function `hasOne` in it

#### Okay so how to avoid this error?

Make sure you're calling the relationship defined in the model from an instance of the model, not a Query Builder

#### Example

Wrong

```php
User::where('name', 'John Doe')->teams;
```

Correct

```php
User::where('name', 'John Does')->first()->teams;
```

#### But why?

Well any SQL operation you make on a model **before** you retreive that model is a Query Builder instance

But once you get the model itself with for example `first()` then you can call the relationship

#### Update: to answer the question's specific scenario

You may want to fetch more than one model so it's not ideal to call the relationship function `team()` on each record **after** it's fetched

#### Solution?

**Eager Loading**

Use the `with` method to include the relationship data with the collection fetched with `get()`

#### Example

Let's say I have a `User` and a `Profile`

Each user has one and only one profile so I define a `hasOne` relationship on the `User` model

```php
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

Now we need a foreign key in the migration to associate the `profiles` table with the `users` table

```php
Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('age'); // Column to test with
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now let's seed some data

```php
public function run()
{
    factory(User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($user) {
        $user->profile()->create(['age' => rand(20, 60)]);
    });
}
```

Now let's open artisan tinker and see what happens

```
>>> App\User::take(10);
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#3067}
```

`take()` function on the User model returns a Builder instance

Let's try to get the profile on that

```
>>> App\User::take(10)->profile();
```

#### Error

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder::profile()'

But now we know why

Now let's try Eager Loading

```
>>> App\User::take(10)->with('profile');
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#3056}
```

Returns a Query Builder

Let's call `get()` on that

```
>>> App\User::take(10)->with('profile')->get();
```

Now we get our collection of data

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3070
     all: [
       App\User {#3022
         id: 1,
         name: "Augusta Botsford MD",
         email: "xwaelchi@example.net",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3095
           id: 1,
           age: 29,
           user_id: 1,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3017
         id: 2,
         name: "Olga Leannon",
         email: "ufay@example.com",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3096
           id: 2,
           age: 24,
           user_id: 2,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3019
         id: 3,
         name: "Bria Prosacco DDS",
         email: "hartmann.trystan@example.com",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3097
           id: 3,
           age: 43,
           user_id: 3,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3054
         id: 4,
         name: "Clare Bayer",
         email: "rosalinda60@example.org",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3098
           id: 4,
           age: 52,
           user_id: 4,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3058
         id: 5,
         name: "Vickie Kub",
         email: "katherine.abbott@example.com",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3099
           id: 5,
           age: 42,
           user_id: 5,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3059
         id: 6,
         name: "Tressie Gottlieb",
         email: "elmira.osinski@example.net",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3100
           id: 6,
           age: 21,
           user_id: 6,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3042
         id: 7,
         name: "Saige Pollich",
         email: "gkemmer@example.org",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3101
           id: 7,
           age: 24,
           user_id: 7,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3087
         id: 8,
         name: "Dr. Emiliano Sauer",
         email: "marks.florida@example.net",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3102
           id: 8,
           age: 42,
           user_id: 8,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3086
         id: 9,
         name: "Genoveva Abshire",
         email: "colt.harber@example.com",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3103
           id: 9,
           age: 27,
           user_id: 9,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
       App\User {#3088
         id: 10,
         name: "Dimitri Moore",
         email: "slockman@example.net",
         email_verified_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         profile: App\Profile {#3104
           id: 10,
           age: 30,
           user_id: 10,
           created_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
           updated_at: "2019-09-30 16:40:12",
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

I hope this clears up some confusion

Comment: What must be happen `User::where('name', 'John Does')->first()->teams;` when no any user with `John Does` name?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @Davit you'd get a `trying to access a property teams on null` and that was just an example illustration

Comment: @CaddyDZ, Nice reply. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Coming from Node with Sequelize ORM this is actually very weird and looks a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
$staff_picks = User::notAdmin()
    ->active()
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->with('team', 'athlete')
    ->get();
```